# Current density defined by the scattering operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, electric-current

I have a problem with the definition of the current density. In most literature it is defined as $j^\mu=\frac{i}{2}(S^*\frac{\partial S(A)}{\partial A_\mu(x)})$. I understand that normally we use Noether's theorem and here we are aware of the gauge invariance of the S-operator. But how I can see the dependence between these two?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: *What* literature? Also, it's a definition. The dependence between which two things here do you want to see?